# How to make tap device use socket API?

Tags: sockets, linux-kernel, tap, tun

I'm using tap device.

The problem is that you just can `->read()` or `->write()` one packet every system call.

After read the source file *tun.c*, I found there is `struct socket` in tun device and function `tun_get_socket()` can return it.

```c
struct socket *tun_get_socket(struct file *file)
{
    struct tun_file *tfile;
    if (file->f_op != &tun_fops)
        return ERR_PTR(-EINVAL);
    tfile = file->private_data;
    if (!tfile)
        return ERR_PTR(-EBADFD);
    return &tfile->socket;
}
EXPORT_SYMBOL_GPL(tun_get_socket);
```

The `socket.ops` is set with `tun_socket_ops` which have `->sendmsg()` and `->recvmsg()`.

```c
static const struct proto_ops tun_socket_ops = {
    .sendmsg = tun_sendmsg,
    .recvmsg = tun_recvmsg,
    .release = tun_release,
};
```

The questions:

1. How to create one file descriptor to connect with this socket? That makes me to use `->sendmsg()` and `->recvmsg()` in userspace. My OS is CentOS7.9 with kernel version `3.10.0-1160.el7.x86_64`.
2. Or is there other ways I can read or write multiple packets at one time from tap device?

Writing new kernel module is acceptable.

Comment: [Searching for usages of tun_get_socket](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v3.10/ident/tun_get_socket) we can see it's only used by "virtio-net server in host kernel", a virtualization thing that's probably irrelevant to you.

Comment: Someone had a similar question [here](https://www.spinics.net/lists/netdev/msg370834.html) and didn't really get a satisfactory conclusion (other than "do it yourself")